# Is it good using INA213 to amplify +/- 33mV to range 0 -> 3.3V?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement

I need measure AC current range 0 - 25A using current transformer and burden resistor, voltage swing from -33mV to +33mV. I searched and found INA213 ([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ina210)). Can I use 3.3V power supply to INA312 or need 5V? Vref is 1.65V (LM358 buffer from voltage divider) and measure by STM32's ADC. As my title, is INA213 suitable for my case?

Thanks

Comment: What's the frequency range you intend to amplify?

Comment: @Reinderien source is 50hz AC, STM32's ADC run in 6 Mhz, and 300K sps

Answer (score 2):

A 50V/V gain of ±33mV would give you ±1.65V on the output with no reference voltage. If you add 1.65V then that would be 0 to 3.3V. Since the output operates to within 3.1V (depends on the load) you the range would be 0.029V with a 3.3V supply. So if you need the range to be the full 33mV then use a 5V supply.

Comment: Where did this 0.29V number come from?  Should it be .029 instead?  And I think you meant the domain would be 29mV, not the range.

Comment: Sorry forgot the zero

Answer (score 1):

The data sheet section 6.5 shows the output voltage is only guaranteed to v+ - 0.2 V, so with a 3.3 V supply you'd only be guaranteed 3.1 V out.